# thread_local "storage class specified"

Tags: c++, multithreading, thread-local

I declared a thread_local in the private section of my C++ class `thread_local unsigned int counter_ = 0;` and I  keep getting an error "storage class specified for counter_"

Answer (score 1):

From the C++ 17 Standard *12.2 Class members)

> 9 A member shall not be declared with the extern
>   storage-class-speciﬁer. Within a class deﬁnition, a member shall not
>   be declared with the thread_local storage-class-speciﬁer unless also
>   declared static.

Comment: Can you add some color to that excerpt?